# HDMI dissapeared from xrandr

Tags: hdmi, ubuntu-14.04, xrandr

I worked with my notebook which was connected with a monitor through HDMI, and restarted it then. Now xrandr is not seeing HDMI port now, of course monitor says "No signal". Don't know why this happened, I haven't changed any system settings during this session.

OS - Ubuntu 14.04
Video - Intel HD3000, driver - i915

xrandr output`:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0

   1024x768       60.0

   800x600        60.3     56.2

   640x480        59.9

VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

lsmod - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9562211/
Xorg.0.log - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9562269/

Answer (score 0):

Strange, i reinstalled xserver-xorg-video-intel and restarted notebook, all work ok now. Don't know where was problem.